# Many-to-Many relationship, when fetch from database ended up with 0 data though database table has 1

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am working in Spring Boot project with SQLite database.

I have two entities: `User` and `StudyType`. They have many-to-many relationship.

I use annotations from `jakarta.persistence` package to declare this relationship.

The `User` entity:

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // this is the primary key in db table

    private String userId; // this is different from the primary key
    
    private String username;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_study_types",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "study_type_id")
    )
    private Set<StudyType> studyTypes;
```

The `StudyType` entity:

```
@Table(name = "study_types")
@Entity
@Data
public class StudyType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studyTypes")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

This code also creates a intermediate database table `user_study_types` in SQLite databse.

When I run this spring boot project, I checked that there are three tables created in database: `users`, `study_types` and `user_study_types`. No problem here.

**Then, I manually populated some data into database** by the following SQL:

For tables `users` and `study_types`:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, username) VALUES('user01', 'username01');
INSERT INTO study_types (name) VALUES ('intermediate'), ('advanced');
```

For the intermediate table `user_study_types`:

```
INSERT INTO user_study_types (user_id, study_type_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2);
```

The above inserted data basically created a user whose `userId`(NOT `id`) is `user01` & has two `studyTypes` which are `intermediate` and `advanced`.

**Then, I try to retrieve data:**

In my project code:

```
User user = userRepository.findByUserId('user01')
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException());
```

At runtime, I can see the retrieved `user` is indeed the one in database, but it has **0** `studyTypes` in size.

Why? What do I miss? I expected this `user` instance should contain **2** `studyTypes` according to what is inserted in the intermediate table `user_study_types`.

Comment: The eager etc. are only honoured if you use the `findById`, which result in the `entityManager.find` call. When you are using `findBy<Property>` it will create a query which will ommit the metadata for generating the query. If you want to load the relation, you need to add an `@EntityGraph` or write a query with a `JOIN.

Comment: Could you please provide examples? e.g. If I write query with `JOIN`, the result would be more than one records with repeated `client.*` since the study_types returns two.

Comment: No it won't as hibernate will map it correctly (I would suggest a read on JPA and how it works). But on your `findByUserId` add `@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "studyTypes"}` this will automatically retrieve the `studyTypes`. Another thing, don't use `@Data` for entities, why see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/